# How to specify <id> and <url> in <repository> section of pom.xml with Tycho if want to add a local p2 update site in RCP application development?

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-rcp, maven-3, tycho

I'm running a local p2 update site by following [this](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin), next I want to use Maven and Tycho plugin to build my plug-in project. How can I add the local p2 update site into pom.xml? In particular, I don't know how to fill in `<id>` and `<url>`. For now. my `<repository>` section is as following.

```
<repositories>  
    <repository>  
      <id>neon</id>  
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon</url>  
      <layout>p2</layout>  
    </repository>       
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm running a local p2 update site by following this, next I want to use Maven and Tycho plugin to build my plug-in project. How can I add the local p2 update site into pom.xml? In particular, I don't know how to fill in  and . For now. my  section is as following.

- `<id>` can be arbitrary, but should be unique in your build (i.e., no two `<url>`s should have the same `<id>`).
- `<url>` needs to be an `http:` URL pointing to the contents of your local p2 update site (what gets put into the `target/repository` directory by the `p2-maven-plugin`. Quoting the [`README` of the `p2-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin#how-to-use-it-in-2-minutes):

  > Unfortunately, it's not the end of the story since tycho does not support local repositories (being more precise: repositories located in a local folder). The only way to work it around is to expose our newly created update site using an HTTP server. We're going to use the jetty-plugin - don't worry, the example above contains a sample jetty-plugin set-up. Just type 'mvn jetty:run' and open the following link http://localhost:8080/site. Your P2 update site will be there!

I hope that is enough to get you started.